# GCP Pub/Sub throws "The Application Default Credentials are not available"

Tags: eclipse, macos, authentication, exception, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to publish to Google Pub/Sub topic using the following:

```
ProjectTopicName topicName = ProjectTopicName.of("my-project-id", "my-topic-id");
Publisher publisher = null;

try {
  // Create a publisher instance with default settings bound to the topic
  publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();

  List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("first message", "second message");

  for (final String message : messages) {
    ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
    PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build();

    // Once published, returns a server-assigned message id (unique within the topic)
    ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);

    // Add an asynchronous callback to handle success / failure
    ApiFutures.addCallback(
        future,
        new ApiFutureCallback<String>() {

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            if (throwable instanceof ApiException) {
              ApiException apiException = ((ApiException) throwable);
              // details on the API exception
              System.out.println(apiException.getStatusCode().getCode());
              System.out.println(apiException.isRetryable());
            }
            System.out.println("Error publishing message : " + message);
          }

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(String messageId) {
            // Once published, returns server-assigned message ids (unique within the topic)
            System.out.println(messageId);
          }
        },
        MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
  }
} finally {
  if (publisher != null) {
    // When finished with the publisher, shutdown to free up resources.
    publisher.shutdown();
    publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }
}
```

I have changed the default values you see here to the particulars of the account I am hitting.

The environment variable points to the JSON file containing the pub/sub authentication credentials:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

was set using:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/file.json
```

and verified with `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` - after a reboot.

But I am still encountering:

```
The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available
if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable 
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining 
the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-
default-credentials for more information.
```

I believe this is related to the default environment that the application is running in, or rather what GCP object thinks the context is -`runningOnComputeEngine`:

```
com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
INFO: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
```

also, a dialog displayed:

```
Unable to launch App Engine Server
Cannot determine server execution context
```

and there are no Google Cloud Platform settings in project (Eclipse 2019-3):

[image: GCP Eclipse Settings]

This is not an App Engine application.

> How to set the environment that GCP objects point to -> Non App Engine.

**For reference:**

- [Server to Server](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application)  (link in error message)
- [Publish](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher)
- [Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart)
- Java 7 application
- Mac OS (Sierra)
- The file permissions are set that app can read the file.

Comment: Did you use export when you set the variable, as in `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=something`? If not, the value will be set in your shell, but not in the child process.

Comment: @CharlesEngelke Yes I did.

Comment: can you try to run this command to set the default credentials "gcloud auth application-default login"

Comment: @Christopher  I do not have that tool present on my system.

Comment: Hi Roy, you should install the SDK[1] for MacOS before either setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or running the command "gcloud auth application-default login"

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Comment: Correction: you don't need the SDK to set the env variable.

Comment: Aside: The Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse by default installs and manages its own Google Cloud SDK. The path should be shown in _Preferences > Google Cloud Tools_ and hovering over the SDK version number.  On macOS, it's typically `~/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST`

Comment: Is this from an App Engine app?  Or a standalone Java program?  Please do tell us more, and describe how you're attempting to launch this program.  Your error dialog sounds like you're launching a web server but without any servlet projects.

Comment: @BriandeAlwis - I explicitly state in the post this is NOT a App Engine application, but a server to server implementation - a Java stand alone app that I am trying to run locally on a Mac.

Comment: I see that now, but the dialog text is puzzling.  FWIW, your example worked for me with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.  But the inconsistencies between services is maddening.

Comment: @BriandeAlwis   Plz elaborate on  your `dialog text is puzzling` comment.  Are you referring to the `Unable to launch App Engine Server` or the Eclipse properties dialog GCP settings?

Comment: Yes, the _Unable to Launch App Engine Server_.  I'm struggling to think how that could be triggered by a standalone Java application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's documentation on this is terrible - it does not mention this anywhere.

The answer is to use:

```
// create a credentials provider
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(Constants.PUB_SUB_KEY)));

// apply credentials provider when creating publisher
publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
```

The Environment variable usage is either deprecated or the documentation is flat out wrong, or I'm missing something,... which is entirely possible given the poor documentation.